# 'optimize' attribute directive ignored

Tags: c++, linux, optimization, gcc, attributes

I have a project for which optimization has been set to "-Os" for all files via `gcc` command line flags. However, I want to disable optimization for some methods in one of the source files. To accomplish that, I am trying to specify the optimization attribute for those methods. However, `gcc` says that it is ignoring `optimize` attribute during build. Does any one know what the problem is?

```
class C 
{
public:
    int __attribute__((optimize("-O0"))) foo();
    .
    .
 };
```

I am using gcc version 4.4.3.

Answer (score 3):

Drop the `-`. It is not required (or probably not expected).

Comment: Tried it. But that does not affect the outcome.

Comment: Normally I would just use the pragma directive, but in the source, not the header.

Comment: It is ignoring `#pragma GCC optimize 0` as well.

Comment: @Rajorshi: You need `#pragma GCC optimize ("O0")`

Comment: Hmm. I think GCC accepts the former as well. Anyway, I tried the following but it did not work either:

    #pragma GCC push_options
    #pragma GCC optimize ("O0")
    .
    .
    .
    #pragma GCC pop_options

Comment: It seems gcc is ignoring the `push_options` and `pop_options` directives as well. So there must be something else wrong with it as it looks like it is ignoring all `pragma` directives and not just the optimization ones.

Comment: it looks like `__attribute__((optimize("0")))` should work, if I'm reading the documentation correctly

Comment: No it doesn't. Is there any way to turn all `#pragma` and `__attribute__` directives off from the commandline? I am wondering if someone has done something like that in the project settings.

Comment: @Rajorshi: Unfortunately not, but you could wrap them in some ifdef perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use optimisation pragmas, as detailed in
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html#Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas

```
#pragma GCC push_options
#pragma GCC optimize ("-O0")
int foo() {
  return bar;
}
#pragma GCC pop_options
```